# Control speed of a gganimation

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I want to slow the transition speed between states when using `library(gganimate)`.

Here is a mini example:

```
# devtools::install_github("thomasp85/gganimate")
library(gganimate) # v0.9.9.9999

dat_sim <- function(t_state, d_state) {
  data.frame(
    x = runif(1000, 0, 1),
    y = runif(1000, 0, 1),
    t_state = t_state*d_state
    )
}

dat <- purrr::map_df(1:100, ~ dat_sim(., 1))

ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_hex(bins = 5) +
  theme_void() +
  lims(x = c(.3, .7),
       y = c(.3, .7)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  transition_time(t_state)
```

[image: toofast]

My ideal behavior would be much slower (10-100x), so color changes gradually evolve and nobody has a seizure.

If I try to use `transition_states()` for more manual control, I get a gif with mostly blank frames. I've tried various combinations for `transition_legnth=` and `state_length=` without a noticeable effect.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_hex(bins = 5) +
  theme_void() +
  lims(x = c(.3, .7),
       y = c(.3, .7)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  transition_states(t_state, transition_length = .1, state_length = 2)
```

[image: mostlyblank]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I found in [docs](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/blob/master/R/animate.R#L17) `animate` function which can take **fps** and **detail** parameters.

> **@param** *fps* The frame rate of the animation in frames/sec
>
> **@param** *detail* The number of additional frames to calculate, per frame

The result:

```
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) +
      geom_hex(bins = 5) +
      theme_void() +
      lims(x = c(.3, .7),
           y = c(.3, .7)) +
      theme(legend.position = "none") +
      transition_time(t_state)
animate(p, fps=1)
```

[image]

Also there you can specify output format such as *png*, *jpeg*, *svg*.